# Structuremap generic type with singleton

Tags: c#, generics, structuremap

I have an issue where I want to use StructureMap to create singletons, but instead StructureMap creates multiple instances. I get confused when trying to read through the documentation on StructureMap on how to handle generics properly.

I have to instantiate a repository for a given entity while providing an instance for the data connection that needs the type of the entity due to generics.

Here is my code for VendorRepository, and many other repositories are structured in the exact same way. IVendorRepository needs IRepository injected with the Vendor type. And I'm not quite sure how to accomplish that in a singleton way.

```
public interface IVendorRepository {
    ...
}

public class VendorRepository : IVendorRepository {
    private readonly IRepository<Vendor> _repository;

    public VendorRepository(IRepository<Vendor> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    ...
}

public class Vendor : DomainEntity
{
    ...
}

public class DomainEntity : IDomainEntity
{
    ...
}
```

Here is the the data connection portion. SqlRepository handles the actual connection via the currentSession. As far as I can tell, each DomainEntity repository (such as VendorRepository) would need it's own instance of the SqlRepository.

```
public class SqlRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IDomainEntity
{
    private readonly ISession _currentSession;

    public SqlRepository(ISession currentSession)
    {
        _currentSession = currentSession;
    }
    ...
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : IDomainEntity
{
    ...
}
```

And finally here is where everything gets wired up today. Using this code, every time VendorRepository is injected, a new instance is created.

```
For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(SqlRepository<>));

For<ISessionSource>()
    .Use(context => ConfigurationSettings.RunAgainstLocalDatabase
        ? (ISessionSource) context.GetInstance<LocalSessionSource>()
        : (ISessionSource) context.GetInstance<LiveSessionSource>());

For<ISession>()
    .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
    .Use(context => context.GetInstance<ISessionSource>().OpenSession());
```

When I tried to use a singleton here, my currentSession was being closed by NHibernate.

```
For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Singleton().Use(typeof(SqlRepository<>));
```

**Edit:**
I'm not entirely sure if this would work as I have a large number of repositories and entities. But I'm currently attempting to add these in by hand to test and see if it would work or not. My end goal is to have singletons of all the entity repositories (such as VendorRepository).

```
For<IRepository<Vendor>>()
            .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
            .Use(context => new SqlRepository<Vendor>(
                 context.GetInstance<ISessionSource>().OpenSession()
            ));
```

**Edit again:**
This appears to be more accurate.. although I'm still not quite sure.

```
For<IVendorRepository>()
    .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
    .Use(context => new VendorRepository(new SqlRepository<Vendor>(context.GetInstance<ISessionSource>().OpenSession())));
```

**Final Edit:**
Here is what needs to happen on a per repository basis. I have no idea how I can do this without listing out every repository as per below (~100). However, in limited testing, using singleton's instead of new instances for every dependency injection had no perceived performance increase. Unless there is an easier way to have StructureMap pick up the repositories and bind them automatically and correctly, I will just leave the way it is where it creates multiple instances as opposed to trying to list out ~100 nearly identical copies of the following code.

```
For<IVendorRepository>()
        .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
        .Singleton()
        .Use(context => new VendorRepository(
            new SqlRepository<Vendor>(context.GetInstance<ISession>())
        ));
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how you would wire this up (create your object graph) if you did this by hand? That would help us understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure thing, I added a bit more on how the graph is created as well as what I'm attempting. I'm quite new to structuremap and have been out of IOC for a while so perhaps my approach is way off base.